# In very simple terms, and code, how would I produce a code that turns a number 1-35, to the written form of that number?

Tags: c++

The problem is we request a number 1-35 from the "user" and with that number, the code can output it in written form. I.e. 1=one, 2=two, and so on. I am currently in my first CS class, and the lab instructor and lecture professor are on two different pages and haven't covered the necessary material to produce this code yet.

So far I have the output and input necessary to request and receive the number from the user. Along with that, I know I will need the const int single = number %10; and const int ten = number / 10; to separate the numbers

this is the code I currently have written.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

int main() {

    cout << "Input a number 1-35 for the days within Japril: ";
    int number;
    cin >> number;

    const int single = number % 10;
    const int ten = number / 10;
```

Comment: to output `"one"` or `"two"` you need those strings somewhere in your code. that would be a start.

Comment: might be that you already did cover the necessary material but you expect this to be more complicated than it is. Apart from what you already posted you need some if statements thats it.

Comment: Start with something really simple: Convert 1 to 9. 1 to 35 isn't quite as simple as do 1 to 9 twice, because of the exceptions like eleven and twelve you can't do 1 to 9 twice, but it isn't too far off if you build one big table mapping strings to numbers for 1 to 35.

Comment: Once you have the simple approach worked out, you can start on doing trickier stuff like two lists, one for the ones and one for the tens, and special cases to handle the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to output "one" for 1 etc...
If that's not the case rephrase your question.
This is the simplest conversion possible (even works at compile time)
Extend to 35 yourself

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

constexpr auto to_text(std::size_t value)
{
    constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 10> numbers
    {
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"
    };

    if (value > 10) throw std::invalid_argument{ "value out of range" };
    return numbers[value];
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(to_text(4) == "four"sv);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you can defines strings for naming the numbers according like this and then you can apply if else conditions for printing the certain number accordingly this can be done in a function and then call the function accordingly for the user input

```
const std::string units[] = {"", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"};
const std::string teens[] = {"", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"};
const std::string tens[] = {"", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty"};

std::string result;



        if (number > 0 && number <= 9) {
            result = units[number];
        } else if (number >= 11 && number <= 19) {
            result = teens[number - 10];
        } else if (number >= 10 && number <= 90 && number % 10 == 0) {
            result = tens[number / 10];
        } else if (number > 20 && number <= 99) {
            result = tens[number / 10] + " " + units[number % 10];
        } else if (number == 20) {
            result = "Twenty";
        } else {
            result = "Invalid input";
        }
    
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: There are a couple of little things not quite right in this code. My biggest gripe is this line: `else if (number > 20 && number <= 99)`.

Comment: It crashes https://godbolt.org/z/48a7hb3YM